# QPlainTextEdit dragEnterEvent not accepting text/uri-list mime types

Tags: c++, windows, qt4

I have the class codeEditor that inherits QPlainTextEdit. I have reimplemented the dragEnterEvent like this:

```
void CodeEditor::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event)
{
    if (event->mimeData()->hasFormat("text/uri-list") || event->mimeData()->hasFormat("text/plain"))
        event->acceptProposedAction();
}
```

And it works for text/plain mime types but for text/uri-list like dragging a file into it. It changes the cursor to indicate it's invalid and if I drop a file it does not work.

Another strange thing it works great in linux. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somebody already reported it as [bug with qt](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-20457)
I am not sure if its been fixed yet.

Please check, it may be useful. :)

Comment: You are absolutely right, that should be the problem. But in the same program it works on another object. Any idea why?

Comment: Microsoft is great..... ;), you will really need windbg and 10 days of work, otherwise shift the question to some msdn forum so that expert there can help you.I think this bug was reported for WINNT alone.